# Plot step-wise decrease in R with Categorical value on X-axis

Tags: r, plot

I want to use a step plot to illustrate a process of elimination. I have a dateframe containing the number of candidates remaining after each step; it looks like this:

```
Step    Candidates Count
1       26587
2       1761
3       849
4       130
```

The **Step** column is a categorical variable and I need to represent with the names of the actual steps; I am using numbers because I have not been able to plot when the **Step** column contains text.

I was able to produce the following figure with the command

```
plot(df, type = "s")
```

[image: Plot]

The problem is the X axis: I need to either get rid of the decimals and add a legend to name each step or, preferably, figure out some way to put the names of the steps in the **Step** column and populate the axis automatically.

I also want to show the same graph as a log but when I use:

```
plot(log(df), type = "s")
```

[image: Logplot]

R gives me log values for both columns. This wouldn't be a problem if I could figure out how to plot the data with **Step** as a categorical variable but I just cannot figure out how.

My instinct is that this is a fairly simple problem but I've been struggling for most of this morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plot(df, type = "s",  xaxt='n', log="y")
axis(1, at=1:4, labels=paste("step", 1:4))
```

Use

`xaxt` to suppress x-axis ticks and labels

`log="y"` to get y-axis on log scale

`axis` to add in the x-axis with `labels` argument used `at` specified points on x-axis

You may also want to tweak the labels on the y-axis

Comment: Excelent answer! Just adding a reference for more info about customization of plots in R: [The Quick-R tutorial: Axes and Text](http://statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html)

Comment: Thanks, thats a really great solution. I set "labels" equal to a list of text. Now my graphs look exactly how I want.